# Typescript interface set values based on logic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a typescript interface which is defined as:

```
interface FutureProjection{
  month1: number;
  month2: number;
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  month12: number;
}
```

This data is used to show the grid on the UI.
I have a logic which is used to find out which month to set data:

```
calculateMonthNum(currentDate:String,futureDate: String):number{
 //Calculate the month difference between future and current.
return monthDiff;
}

functionToSetMonthData(currentDate:String,futureDate: String, projection: FutureProjection, amount: number): FutureProjection{
  const monthNum = calculateDiff(currentDate,futureDate);
  ****//How to do this?? vvvv **
  projection.month+monthNum = amount; //.  <---This assignment operation???
  return projection;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use bracket syntax to access a property of any javascript object.

```
// identical
projection['month1']
projection.month1
```

Which means you can build a string that is the property name and use that in brackets:

```
projection[`month${monthNum}`] = amount;
```

---

But in typescript that only get you half way there. This will get you a type error:

```
type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FutureProjection'.
```

The problem is that `FutureProjection` cannot be indexed by `string`, only specific strings are allowed. So typescript doesn't know that `month${monthNum}` is a specific string that is actually valid since `monthNum` could be any number (-5, 0, 100, 3.14159, etc).

The easiest way to solve that is cast the key string to a `keyof FutureProjection`. Note that in order for this to be safe you must ensure that `calculateDiff()` only ever returns integers 1 through 12.

That looks something like:

```
function setMonthData(currentDate:String,futureDate: String, projection: FutureProjection, amount: number): FutureProjection{
  const monthNum = calculateDiff(currentDate, futureDate);
  const monthKey = `month${monthNum}` as keyof FutureProjection
  projection[monthKey] = amount;
  return projection;
}
```

[Working example on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2&ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=21&pc=1#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-bAFAO+-LpIA)

---

All that said, it may make your life easier to use an array instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that like the following:

```js
  projection[`month${monthNum}`] = amount;
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, as an alternative to a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) like

```
interface FutureProjection {
  [k: string]: number
}
```

which would accept any key whatsoever:

```
declare const f: FutureProjection
f.oopsiedaisy = 123; // no compiler error
```

one might consider using a [*template string pattern index signature*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) as introduced in TypeScript 4.4 to accept only strings that start with `"month"` and are followed by a numeric-like string:

```
interface FutureProjection {
  [k: `month${number}`]: number
}

declare const f: FutureProjection
f.oopsiedaisy = 123; // error
f.month11 = 456; // okay
f.month1234567 = 789; // this is also okay, any number is accepted
```

If you do it this way, then the compiler will automatically allow you to index into a `FutureProjection` with an appropriately constructed [template literal string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
function functionToSetMonthData(currentDate: string, futureDate: string,
  projection: FutureProjection, amount: number
): FutureProjection {
  const monthNum = calculateMonthNum(currentDate, futureDate);
  projection[`month${monthNum}`] = amount; // okay
  return projection;
}
```

---

Note that this doesn't quite serve the purpose of only accepting `month1` through `month12`.  You could decide to replace `number` with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types),

```
type MonthNumber = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12;
interface FutureProjection extends Record<`month${MonthNumber}`, number> { }

declare const f: FutureProjection
f.oopsiedaisy = 123; // error
f.month11 = 456; // okay
f.month1234567 = 789; // error
```

which is great; unfortunately you'd have a hard time convincing the compiler that any of your mathematical operations that produce `number` are really producing a `MonthNumber`, since it doesn't really do math at the type level (see [microsoft/TypeScript#15645](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15645)):

```
declare const i: MonthNumber;
const j: MonthNumber = 13 - i; // error, even though this must be safe
const k: MonthNumber = ((i + 6) % 12) || 12; // error, ditto
```

And so you'd find yourself doing unsafe assertions no matter what as well as some other workarounds:

```
function calculateMonthNum(currentDate: string, futureDate: string): MonthNumber {
  return (((((new Date(futureDate).getMonth() - new Date(currentDate).getMonth())
    % 12) + 12) % 12) || 12) as MonthNumber // <-- assert here
}

function functionToSetMonthData(currentDate: string, futureDate: string,
  projection: FutureProjection, amount: number
): FutureProjection {
  const monthNum = calculateMonthNum(currentDate, futureDate);
  projection[`month${monthNum}` as const] = amount; // <-- const assert here
  return projection;
}

const f = {} as FutureProjection; // assert here
for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) f[`month${i as MonthNumber}`] = 0; // assert here
```

So I'm kind of thinking you'd be better off with `` `month${number}` ``.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlALgJwJbAOYEkATADxS11DQFcNkBvAKCSRzQgwDMFkAxK62gAUMAewBWEeGiwjgSRs2YBtANYAuJFEw5cAXQ3AqYAEbsmSAL7mOVYFJlyQwAJ4BpCM4AUHDXwERhcUlpWQBKeXNmDgA6EREYKCwIQhAsKGckAF4kAEYAJgBmAG5zK2tbe1kkeBAAG3gqWpA2AFlZNAALADkjTwaMWmA0ABFmiA0tbDwAGiQbf1G2Ce08UIMjUwwIxSRaATlPQ8PgCAB3JEWIb34aCEvQ6NwINDahjs9wgFokE-PLvpogxGYweTxe7XeoXCAFJcnlwgBqOEw5FIAA+aORpQY5TsITkNjxDgAKiIUM9Xp1FiAAQMIENLssprhZvNbozNCsWUgYKIJJVgL4bkI+cEHLNwCJbGh1iZ2GskH5boF+fjtop4LItEgwBCemAstU6g0mq09b1+kDLqzhXcQSUdryggKlAADXVvAAkdA9nX1FldukNkulDsUexocidqocYbKzE1wG1PkVtpVYqq2ToViiIi2nlqzxYhpyRWLAB5svky1gEQjwhw3b6Ot6sAGg9kAAwlXEC0nk8FvameABEeU7eRyn07AA5PnkAOwj2ZjidTnJTxfLuazfIFUJhxNQESF6K1ES4byhBhlUCQWDcJDEiBgGCmiAAGSwbAwdUEzR-YAiFIchKFudVWHYLhEFTfx0wFdVlHUJB3Qhb1DDlDB21lTZsSiCo1ScNwPG8IU4NFAVwgURQYjiBIkhSNIMirQoywAejYpB2FEDBIjmaJmw3Q0ABYAFYADZ2M4kQVBAZw+JiQTCjE8SF0NBcZwATikpBOjSFgoCQOpjyQGS5IlFwfg2dgDKM+BEBgNhCGxXs1RqepGjGSlugtQF6WBJZOWZG0FjGJkdAVDDNkQ3ZnkjJAjmOM4LjGa5QrYUEKQhD4kG+X4UrYWkrRBR4sreD4UXyRFUVhKr0UxKqXPwokqkJPsyTKqlmhpS1-I5SYdBC9kwqCwaeQo-EyOVCbxSM3VpRw+UppFZ01WohMtTQHVzQNbJ3JNLydqKvqxiG2h7jDZhowzYAmzQn0dvbYN5qGS7Yv2cbVtjJrqk2uZloCGbM3kHM5jzBLCy2rASxrJBKzhGs6wbO6vToNtA0NbscWa9qB284dV0nac5y3FdxyJjd5yXVld0KA9zCPE8IDPC8rxvHE72gOAYOfV93y-H86gAVWABwInMNBnBgZBvP1aKq3RJA8kVgpFeExXRMV8TFbUzEZ0VzTFZyTsjZyI28jDSDOEfJUVpjKoIGINhgEIQyACVJDzQhy1Q1HZesrDXVmKL2AAPnkSxsbmAixaI9wvBTW3Aa+sIYto+JEmSVJ0hLVikA4riBjzBSBIhITshUnSzPknZFLL5SJLU7INO0-POO44vmFBtq1WbFpmneLANH9zCqL4o8trEYedvl3JVe+LAdI7jAAEJx7+5CR9nw5oaRcTKvheqEbbwueJc1yxf2zyzTefVjoZEaBpmaP0vGUbVmn2+A5iiMMAORL8r-DZOdEqYJvI5Tyslf4vUH4ZVKoOToFU+LMFqofJEdVUHhAxKiEAhkt5mC7lHHuYtiGyH7J1Dow4YEBTfk-bkwC7SBTobMa6AoAbwXxBKF6MorKj3YUDOQ61fpJi2s2fUhor7vhHvfGhZ1GEQHpo6ARKNOjejEUYAMRlDITw7HNKUr0+K-yjAIuMUcJ5zENNmLRsFpop2AGGDg4MCxFmhlWWG8NqwsCRnMFRLY0bWPwYHXRWML5kI6ggyh3VRzkynLOKm25Cbrk3NTHccJ9yHi1EzFml4ODXhxGUBgQA)

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this...

```
projection[`month${monthNum }`] = amount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the interface like

```
interface FutureProjection {
  [month: string]: number
}
```

then set values into the object using template strings

```
projection[`month${monthNum}`] = amount;
```